# Crear un archivo json con los datos de un formulario en Python

Tags: python-3.x, json, tkinter

Soy algo novata con la librería de **json**, el caso es que me gustaría extraer los datos de un formulario que hice con **tkinter** y crear un archivo json cuando oprima el botón y que después de crearlo la ventana se cierre.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import Menu
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import messagebox
import tkinter as tk
import json
import time

class pruebas:

def guardar(self):
    credenciales = {}
    credenciales = []

    credenciales.append({
        "Nombre": "base_input",
        "Ruta": self.text_base_input.get()
    })
    with open('prueba.json','w') as document:
        json.dump(credenciales, document, indent=3)

    self.aniquilar()

def ventana2(self):
    self.window2 = Tk()
    self.window2.title("Configuraciones")
    self.window2.geometry('488x478')
    self.window2.resizable(False,False)

    self.text_base_input = StringVar()

    label_base_input = Label(self.window2,text="Dato")
    label_base_input.pack(padx=10)

    entry_base_input = Entry(self.window2,textvariable=self.text_base_input)
    entry_base_input.pack(padx=10)

    btn_acept = Button(self.window2,
                    text="Aceptar",
                    width=15,
                    relief="flat",
                    font=("Candara",10),
                    borderwidth=1,
                    bg="gray82",
                    command=self.guardar())
    btn_acept.pack(padx=10,pady=10)

    mainloop()

    V = pruebas()
    V.ventana2()
```

En este formato quiero que quede el archivo json, la clave **Nombre** no la voy a modificar esa va ser las misma la que quiero generar o insertar es el valor de la claver **Ruta**.

```
[
 {
  "Nombre": "base input",
  "Ruta": "C:\ruta_de_ejeplo"
 }
]
```

Pero este es el archivo que se genera:

```
[
 {
  "Nombre": "base input",
  "Ruta": ""
 }
]
```

Gracias.

Comment: Cuando haces `command=self.guardar()` estás invocando al método guardar y lo que devuelva queda en `command`, quita los paréntesis: `command=self.guardar`.

Comment: Vale gracias lo intentaré

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu problema nada tiene que ver con *json*.

Cuando creas el botón, tienes esto:

```
btn_acept = Button(self.window2,
               bla, bla, bla
               command=self.guardar())
```

Lo que está ocurriendo es que en ese momento se está invocando al método `guardar()` y lo que ese método devuelva se pasa en el parámetro `command`.

Evidentemente, para entonces, el usuario no ha tenido la oportunidad de introducir nada en  `text_base_input` que está en blanco.

Cuando el usuario hace clic al botón, no se ejecuta el método guardar.

Lo que tu debes pasar en el parámetro `command` es una referencia al método.

En otras palabras: quita los paréntesis, ya que esto hace que se ejecute el método, y pasa solo su *nombre*, que es la referencia:

```
btn_acept = Button(self.window2,
               bla, bla, bla
               command=self.guardar)
```

Ahora si, cuando el usuario haga clic en el botón se ejecutará el método `guardar`. Pruébalo por ti misma poniendo un *breakpoint* en la primera línea del método, ejecuta paso a paso y mira la diferencia de cuando se ejecuta con tu código original y con el que propongo en esta respuesta.

Finalmente, la primera línea del método `guardar()` está de más, puedes quitarla y todo funcionará igual.

Comment: Cuando llamo el formulario desde otrs ventana por medio de los menus no agrega los datos al archivo json, por que?

Comment: Sospecho que esa sería una nueva pregunta, pues habría que ver el código relevante para tratar de entender qué es lo que falla en ese caso.

Comment: en ese caso ya are una edición a la pregunta, avisare cuando lo cambio

Comment: No edites esta pregunta, creo que este tema está resuelto. Haz una nueva pregunta, a menos que tengas una excelente razón para mantenerlo en esta y, probablemente, dejar como inválida esta respuesta.

Comment: lo que digo es solo hacer una ventana con tkinter y agregarle un menú desde ese menú llamo al formulario e ingreso los datos oprimo un botón "Aceptar" para que me cree el archivo json.

Comment: De verdad no se me ocurre por qué podría fallar. Si publicas una nueva pregunta déjame saber y veo si le encuentro el problema. Un saludo.

Comment: aca esta la publicacion nuvea que hice hacerca del programa https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/449504/el-archivo-json-no-recibe-los-datos-del-formulario-en-python